# Organize screen components when touched

Tags: typescript, react-native

I want to know how can I make it so that even when the TextInput boxes are clicked the screen stays on place, or so that it scrolls over to the box you want to fill.

[Screen with nothing going on.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ESkl8.png)

[Screen when there is something going on.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oZ41p.png)

As you can see the screen goes all over the place, somethings go over the title and it becomes a mess.

Code:

```
        <Text style={{fontSize:27, color:'white', top: 5, textAlign:'center'}}>Cálculo do Traço a partir das Medidas:</Text>
        
        <View style={styles.container}>
            <View style={styles.inputContainer}>
                <Text style={styles.label}>Agressividade</Text>
                <TextInput
                style={styles.input}
                placeholder="Insira aqui"
                keyboardType='decimal-pad'
                returnKeyType={ 'done' }
                onChangeText={(text) => calculo(text)}
                />
            </View>
            <View style={styles.inputContainer}>
                <Text style={styles.label}>Condição</Text>
                <TextInput
                style={styles.input}
                placeholder="Insira aqui"
                keyboardType='decimal-pad'
                returnKeyType={ 'done' }
                onChangeText={(text) => calculo(text)}
                />
            </View>
            <View style={styles.inputContainer}>
                <Text style={styles.label}>Tipo de cimento</Text>
                <TextInput
                style={styles.input}
                placeholder="Insira aqui"
                keyboardType='decimal-pad'
                returnKeyType={ 'done' }
                onChangeText={(text) => calculo(text)}
                />
            </View>
            <View style={styles.inputContainer}>
                <Text style={styles.label}>fck</Text>
                <TextInput
                style={styles.input}
                placeholder="Insira aqui"
                keyboardType='decimal-pad'
                returnKeyType={ 'done' }
                onChangeText={(text) => calculo(text)}
                />
            </View>
            <View style={styles.inputContainer}>
                <Text style={styles.label}>Slump</Text>
                <TextInput
                style={styles.input}
                placeholder="Insira aqui"
                keyboardType='decimal-pad'
                returnKeyType={ 'done' }
                onChangeText={(text) => calculo(text)}
                />
            </View>
            <View style={styles.inputContainer}>
                <Text style={styles.label}>Dimensão máxima</Text>
                <TextInput
                style={styles.input}
                placeholder="Insira aqui"
                keyboardType='decimal-pad'
                returnKeyType={ 'done' }
                onChangeText={(text) => calculo(text)}
                />
            </View>
            <View style={styles.inputContainer}>
                <Text style={styles.label}>Idade</Text>
                <TextInput
                style={styles.input}
                placeholder="Insira aqui"
                keyboardType='decimal-pad'
                returnKeyType={ 'done' }
                onChangeText={(text) => calculo(text)}
                />
            </View>
            <View style={styles.inputContainer}>
              
                <Text style={styles.label}>Método de dosagem</Text>
              
                <Picker style={styles.input}>
                    <Picker.Item key={0} label='ABCP' value='ABCP' style={{fontSize:25}} />
                    <Picker.Item key={1} label='IPT' value='IPT' style={{fontSize:25}} />
                </Picker>
              
            </View>
        </View>
```

Styles used:

```
container: {
    flex: 1,
    justifyContent: 'center',
    alignItems:"center"
},
input:{
    width:"48%",
    borderBottomColor:"#585858",
    borderBottomWidth:2,
    fontSize: 25,
    color:'white'
},
inputContainer:{
    flexDirection:"row",
    justifyContent:"space-between",
    alignItems:"center",
    marginVertical:10
},
label: {
    width:"48%",
    fontSize:25,
    color: 'white'
},
```

Comment: after testing KeyboardAvoidingView and a ScrollView I found the second one better. However the 'result' button (the grey one on the lower part of the screen) is still going out of place. Do you know how I can make it disappear when touching an Input box?

Answer (score 0):

Ok I figured it out, all I needed to do was set some conditions for it to render:

```
const[shouldShow, setshouldShow] = useState(true);
<ScrollView contentContainerStyle={{flexGrow: 1, justifyContent: 'center'}}>
 <TextInput
  style={styles.input}
  onFocus={() => setshouldShow(!shouldShow)}
  onBlur={() => setshouldShow(!shouldShow)}
  placeholder="Insira aqui"
  keyboardType='decimal-pad'
  returnKeyType={ 'done' }
  />
  
 {
   shouldShow ? (
     <TouchableOpacity
      style= {styles.butResult}>
       <Text style={{fontSize:25, textAlign: 'center', 
        paddingTop:'auto'}}>Ver Resultado</Text> 
     </TouchableOpacity>
    ) : null
   }
```